# Renew Push certificate and keep current App Store App working xcode 8.3.3

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-push-notifications

I need to revoke the APNS certificates as they are going to expire soon. **I checked many answer but all questions are very old.**

As when we create the APNS certificate then they need to add to key chain and then create the app for app store. So Are these certificates are used while creating ipa file.

**My question is** if I revoke and create APNS certificates the should i need to upload app to appstore again or should i just create new and change them on backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to recompile the app or resubmit the app to AppStore. Just create a new APNS certificate and test it with your current app. Once everything is fine, revoke the old certificate.